# Passing a stack object address to make a copy

Tags: c++, pointers

I have seen the code that does passing of arguments in a similar way as the following implementation of the execute() function. Is it perfectly legal or acceptable? It seems to work but is it correct? Could you also explain what is going on with values vector?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<string> GetValues()
{
    return vector<string> {"hello", "world"};
}

void execute(vector<string>* values)
{
    *values = GetValues();
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> values;
    execute(&values);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << values[i].c_str() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's absolutely fine, if a little clumsy. Lots of potential for unnecessary value copies being taken: the compiler might optimise some away.

Comment: yes that's fine. but can you share any practical use cases why you're doing this?

Comment: @Bathsheba what copy? I see a move at most.

Comment: code works, not cannot really be considered modern C++ style. Many improvements possible.

Comment: Adress of the `values` vector is being sent to your `execute()` function, in which, there is a vector pointer called `values`. So basically `values` parameter in `execute()` points to the address of the `values` vector from the main. Function dereferences the `values` pointer, thus accessing the address it points, and assigns the vector returned by the `GetValues()` to the address of the `values` vector from the main function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is legal, although of course a contrived example.

Remember what the term "stack" means in Comp.Sci. It's a container with more than one element, but one element is designated top. Which element that is changes with push and pop operations. It's therefore the typical "Last In First Out" datastructure.

That's also why we talk about the function call stack. Function calls and function returns work the same way as push and pops. The last-called function is "top", and that's where code is executing. Also, for all functions on the call stack, local variables are live, but only those of the top function can be accessed **directly**.

I've bolded "directly" because your example shows a workaround. You pass a pointer from `main` to `execute` so you can indirectly access `values` in `main` while `execute` is running. This is safe because it's a stack. `main` cannot return while `execute` runs; `execute` has to return fist. And thus `execute` can safely use `values` from `main`.

This is all safe due to stack semantics. But if you start deviating from this, e.g. by storing pointers, you need to start worrying about object lifetimes. And that's quite a bit more complex because C++ has no garbage collection. Use the stack semantics where possible, it's just easier.

Comment: The value returned by GetValues() is still copied (or moved). Would it be better to just return GetValues() from execute() as a result?

Comment: @Industrious: Yes, that's better. It will be moved, and that's efficient. Moving a vector doesn't even move the vector elements themselves; typically it only moves a pointer (`.data()`), an element count (`.size()`) and the memory allocation (`.capacity()`).